# Error code when compiling in Java

Tags: java

Ok so I'm trying to get my code to give me a return type but it keeps giving me an error.
Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gradebookmodified {
        public static void main(String[] args ){
            mainMenu();
            mainInstructions();
            mainGrades();
            average();
        }

        public static void mainMenu(){  
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Choose an option: \n1.Average grades for a new student \n2.Quit \n");
            int selection;
            selection = input.nextInt();
            if( selection == 1){
                System.out.println("Enter name of new student");
                String name = input.next();
            }else {
            }
        }

        public static void mainInstructions(){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Grades will be entered in this order: \n1. Homework \n2. Quizzes \n3. Tests");
        }

        public static void mainGrades(){
            Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

            double[] homework = new double[5];
            for(int i = 0; i < homework.length; i++){
                System.out.println("Enter homework grades.");
                homework[i] = input.nextDouble();
            }

            double[] quizzes = new double[4];
            for(int j = 0; j <quizzes.length; j++){
                System.out.println("Enter quiz grades.");
                quizzes[j] = input.nextDouble();
            }

            double[] tests = new double[4];
            for(int k = 0; k <tests.length; k++){
                System.out.println("Enter test grades.");
                tests[k] = input.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        public static double average(double homework, int i){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            double result = 0.0;
            if (homework > 0){
                result = i / homework;
            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

This is the error that the compiler keeps giving me.

```
Gradebookmodified.java:16: error: method average in class Gradebookmodified cannot be applied to given types;
        average();
        ^
required: double,int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Im not sure why it keeps giving me this error but if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be fantastic.

Comment: average(); takes two parameters, whom you're not passing to it. average(double, int);

Comment: In your `main()` method you call `average()` but you define `average(double, int)`. And all of the grades are local to `mainGrade()`.

Comment: You can do one task.Mark every variable(which are used in later functions) in your static functions as static.And simply make a call to average function.Also change your Function definition for average to average()
{
//function body goes here
}

Answer (score 2):

you have used `average();` in your main method

but your average function signature is

```
average(double homework, int i)
```

**Note**: As you see your usage of average function in main method does not agree with your function signature.

Comment: Ok. So how would I go about fixing this? I can't seem to figure out how to get the average of each 3 of the categories I have(homework, quizzes, tests). Im am just at a loss at the moment.

Comment: Do not worry. just could you explain more what your issue is?

Comment: Ok, this program is suppose to get an average for each of the groups that are listed in the code (homework, quizzes, tests). At the end of the code we are suppose to give a final average of all the grades.  This is all suppose to be done using multiple methods. I've tried running my code without average(); in my main method. It works, but it skips over my average method at the bottom of my code which is also a problem. The code is also suppose to use arrays and I'm not to sure how to average user inputs from arrays. It's something I have yet to learn in class and it has put me to a halt.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your average method as

```
public static double average(double homework, int i)
```

So when you calling it you should pass a double and a int argument to that method.

The error is that in your code you are calling it without any parameters. `average();`

You must call it like
e.g.

```
double homework = 2.3; // some value
int i = 1; // some value
average(homework, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass 3 parameters when you call the " average() " method. When you calling the "average()" i can't see that you did not pass any parameter. That is why compiler can not compile the code.

Number of method parameters should be match with number of method arguments. Otherwise compiler can not compile the code.

When you calling the "average()" method, you should pass three parameters as follows,

average(5.5, 5);

Using above code and try to continue rest of your works

Good Luck!!!!!